# R code in Beamer

Tags: beamer, listings

I have an R code as `print("hello")`. But it prints out 2 line for 1 line code. How to get around with this. Many thanks in advance. [image: 2]

```
   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass[10pt,english,8pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
    backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},    
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{magenta},
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
    stringstyle=\color{codepurple},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
    breakatwhitespace=false,         
    breaklines=true,                 
    captionpos=b,                    
    keepspaces=true,                 
    numbers=left,                    
    numbersep=5pt,                  
    showspaces=false,                
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,                  
    tabsize=2
}

\lstset{style=mystyle}
\begin{document}




\begin{frame}[fragile]{NAME}
    

    \begin{lstlisting}[language=R]
    print("hello")
    \end{lstlisting}
    \vskip0pt 
    
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: No spaces before especially `\end{lstlisting}`. Verbatim like constructions are very particular about indentation of the environment as they eat **everything** up until the end part of the env. So here the spaces after the line break of the `print` command up to `\end{lstlisting}` are being interpreted as part of the listing

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verbatim-like constructions like `lstlisting` reads everything until `\end{lstlisting}`. Thus if we write

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]{NAME}

    \begin{lstlisting}[language=R]
    print("hello")
    \end{lstlisting}
    \vskip0pt 
    
\end{frame}
```

then the spaces from the left edge to `\end{lstlisting}` will also be read, and that produces the extra line in the out put.

Thus use

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]{NAME}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=R]
print("hello")
\end{lstlisting}
    
\end{frame}
```